# Basis of a Kernel

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential, homogeneous-equation

How would i find the basis of the kernel of the differential operator below

$$8y'' + 3y' + 7y$$

We know the equation was homogenous and i believe the basis is two dimensional

Comment: As is that isn't a differential equation. Do you mean $8y''+3y'+7y=0$?

Comment: It is a differential operator.

Comment: Yes this is a differential operator

Comment: Try $y \mapsto e^{\alpha y}$ and see what values of $\alpha$ work. You need to show that the kernel is two dimensional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key here is that for any $x_0, v_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a unique solution $x$ to the differential equation that satisfies $x(0) = x_0, x'(0) = v_0$.

If we let $L$ be the differential operator above, then this shows that the
linear map $i: \ker L \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by
$i(y) = (y(0),y'(0))$ is bijective, and hence $\dim \ker L = \dim \mathbb{R}^2 = 2$.

Define the function $e_\alpha$ by
$e_\alpha(t) = e^{\alpha t}$.
Note that if $\alpha_1 \neq \alpha_2$, then the functions $e_{\alpha_1}, e_{\alpha_2}$ are linearly independent. To see this, suppose
$\beta_1 e_{\alpha_1} + \beta_2 e_{\alpha_2} = 0$. By evaluating $e_\alpha(0), e'_\alpha(0)$  we have
$\beta_1 + \beta_2  = 0$ and
$\beta_1 \alpha_1 + \beta_2\alpha_2 = 0$ from which we have $\beta =0$.

Note that $L e_\alpha = (8 \alpha^2+3 \alpha+7) e_\alpha$, 
hence $L e_\alpha = 0$ **iff** $\alpha$  satisfies $8 \alpha^2+3 \alpha+7 = 0$.

Let $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ be the two distinct values of $\alpha$ that satisfy the quadratic.

Then $\ker L = \operatorname{sp} \{ e_{\alpha_1}, e_{\alpha_2} \} $.

Comment: Is the basis always exponential?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. The functions $e_{\alpha_1}+e_{\alpha_2}$, $e_{\alpha_1}-e_{\alpha_2}$ also form a basis. Do you consider then to be 'exponential'?

Comment: Yes sorry if im not clear, what about the function say, y'' wouldn't a suitable basis be {1,t^2} ? as both multiplied by y'' = 0

Comment: If the quadratic has a repeated root $\alpha$, then you can show that $t \mapsto e^{\alpha t}$ and $t \mapsto t e^{\alpha t}$ are two linearly independent solutions, hence a basis. In the example of your last comment, $\alpha = 0$, which gives rise to the basis $t \mapsto 1, t \mapsto t$. The function $t \mapsto t^2$ doesn't satisfy $y'' = 0$. But I'm not sure what relevance this has to the question.

Comment: Im not sure what you exactly mean by repeated root in this case - how did you arise to a basis of {1,t}

Comment: You asked about an equation $y''=0.$ Let $My = y''$, and looking for exponential solutions gives $M e_\alpha = \alpha^2 e_\alpha$, hence $Me_\alpha = 0$ **iff** $\alpha = 0$. However since the quadratic $\alpha^2 = 0$ only has one solution, this is not sufficient for a basis, so you need to look for other solutions. So, look at $t \mapsto t e_\alpha(t)$.

Comment: Thank you, could you just confirm from this how you would get {1,t} as a basis?

Comment: The functions $t \mapsto e_\alpha(t), t \mapsto te_\alpha(t)$ are linearly independent. And if you set $\alpha = 0$ both satisfy $y''=0$. And the first part of the analysis in the answer holds for any 2nd order linear ode. Hence $t \mapsto 1, t \mapsto t$ form a basis.

Comment: Thank you, i feel i understand

Answer (score 2):

You will need to solve the differential equation: $$8y'' + 3y' + 7y = 0$$ and we can do this with the characteristic equation which can be found by assuming our solution is a power of an exponential: $y= e^{rx}$ which yields: $$(8r^2+3r+7)e^{rx} = 0$$ and so $r = \frac{-3 \pm i\sqrt{216}}{16}$

This leads to the two linearly independent solutions: $$y_1 = e^{(-3)x} \cdot\left(\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{216}}{16}x\right) + i \sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{216}}{16}x\right)\right)$$
$$y_2 = e^{(-3)x} \cdot\left(\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{216}}{16}x\right) - i \sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{216}}{16}x\right)\right)$$

In order to have two solutions with strictly real terms, we combine these as $z_1 = y_1+y_2$ and $z_2 =-i (y_1-y_2)$ to get:

$$z_1= 2e^{-3x} \cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{216}}{16}x\right)$$ and
$$z_2 = 2e^{-3x} \sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{216}}{16}x\right)$$

Comment: How do you know that this is a basis for the kernel?

Comment: I didn't make that claim. I found two linearly independent functions in the kernel space. In order to show that the basis is precisely two dimensional, you need to think about the function space where the solutions are coming from.

Comment: That was the question.

Comment: What you can do is first demonstrate that every solution to this differential equation is infinitely differentiable, and that each one is an entire function. After that you can work out a dependency on the coefficients and this will show that there are precisely two degrees of freedom.

Comment: Am i not just looking for something to multiply the kernel by, such that the product is 0?

Comment: The problem is twofold. The first is to determine the dimension of the kernel of your linear operator. Which we are assuming is two. After that, you must find exactly which two functions will span the space. I have answered the second here for you.

Comment: Ok thanks, so if i multiply each of your solutions by the kernel, i will get 0?

Comment: Yes, if my algebra works out :P

Answer (score 1):

Let $z_1, z_2$ the roots of the characteristic equation. Let $\Delta$ the 
 differential operator, let $D$ be the derivation operator. Let $P = (X-z_1)(X-z_2)$.

Then as $z_1\neq z_2$,
$\gcd(X-z_1, X-z_2) = 1 $ and
 some algebra theorem ensures that
$$
\ker \Delta = \ker P(D) = \ker (D-z_1I) \oplus  \ker (D-z_2I)
$$

This leads to the result of Joel.

Comment: Great thank you all, i understand! However what if you "can't" make a characteristic equation, ie somthing like;
y'' + y'/y +k where k is constand

Comment: @MathsPro is this case, use the variation of constants to find a solution. Elementary linear algebra proves that if there is a solution, then the space of solutions is affine (and directed by the kernel of the differential operator).